# Splitting lists of lists into two lists of lists, based on duplicates in one of the original list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists

```
queryBounds = [[2, 1924], [2, 1924], [2187, 2233], [2187, 2233]]
sequenceBounds = [[95516, 97442], [139777, 137851], [97433, 97479], [137860, 137814]]
```

I would like to split `queryBounds` into two lists `queryBoundsA` and `queryBoundsB` so that there are no duplicates in either list i.e.

```
queryBoundsA = [[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]]
queryBoundsB = [[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]]
```

I then want to split `sequenceBounds` into two lists `sequenceBoundsA` and `sequenceBoundsB` so that the items in `sequenceBounds` that had the same index as the items `queryBounds` move into either `queryBoundsA` or `queryBoundsB`, and their list index matches where the items with the same index from `sequenceBounds` has gone.

```
sequenceBoundsA = [[95516, 97442], [97433, 97479]]
sequenceBoundsB = [[139777, 137851], [137860, 137814]]
```

I also need this to work for when `queryBounds` only contains duplicates:

```
queryBounds = [[2, 2233], [2, 2233]]
sequenceBounds = [[111722, 113939], [166447, 164230]]

queryBoundsA = [[2, 2233]]
queryBoundsB = [[2, 2233]]

sequenceBoundsA = [[111722, 113939]]
sequenceBoundsB = [[166447, 164230]]
```

I cannot work out how to do this

Comment: Question: What should happen if there are **three** occurrences of an item in the queryBounds list? Or is this sufficiently unlikely to occur?

Comment: on what basis you are seggregating queryBoundsA and queryBoundsB, a larger test data would be easier to understand

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service, and we generally do not deal with code design.
If you want help, expand your example to a full specification and post your problem code. (see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) ).

Comment: The best strategy may well depend on what you want to use these pairs for. I can imagine that splitting the lists might be a waste of time when you can iterate through the zipped lists and check for duplicates as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a dictionary do the hard work.  This will handle more than 2 copies:

```
queryBounds = [[2, 1924], [2, 1924], [2187, 2233], [2187, 2233]]
sequenceBounds = [[95516, 97442], [139777, 137851], [97433, 97479], [137860, 137814]]

# Create a dict:

sorter = {}
for q, s in zip(queryBounds,sequenceBounds):
    q = tuple(q)
    if q not in sorter:
        sorter[q] = [s]
    else:
        sorter[q].append( s )

# Print the results:
qb = [[]]
sb = [[]]
for k, v in sorter.items():
    for i,v1 in enumerate(v):
        if i >= len(qb):
            qb.append( [] )
            sb.append( [] )
        qb[i].append( list(k) )
        sb[i].append( v1 )

print( qb )
print( sb )
```

Output:

```
[[[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]], [[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]]]
[[[95516, 97442], [97433, 97479]], [[139777, 137851], [137860, 137814]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
def split_bounds(query, seq):
   r = list(zip(*[list(b) for _, b in gb(enumerate(query), key=lambda x:x[-1])]))
   query_r = [[b for _, b in i] for i in r]
   seq_r = [[seq[a] for a, _ in i] for i in r]
   return query_r, seq_r
```

---

```
queryBounds1 = [[2, 1924], [2, 1924], [2187, 2233], [2187, 2233]]
sequenceBounds1 = [[95516, 97442], [139777, 137851], [97433, 97479], [137860, 137814]]
queryBounds2 = [[2, 2233], [2, 2233]]
sequenceBounds2 = [[111722, 113939], [166447, 164230]]
query1, seq1 = split_bounds(queryBounds1, sequenceBounds1)
query2, seq2 = split_bounds(queryBounds2, sequenceBounds2)
```

Output:

```
[[[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]], [[2, 1924], [2187, 2233]]]
[[[95516, 97442], [97433, 97479]], [[139777, 137851], [137860, 137814]]]
[[[2, 2233]], [[2, 2233]]]
[[[111722, 113939]], [[166447, 164230]]]
```